# Iterating through a JSON object

Tags: python, dictionary, loops

I am trying to iterate through a JSON object to import data, i.e. title and link. I can't seem to get to the content that is past the `:`.

**JSON:**

```
[
    {
        "title": "Baby (Feat. Ludacris) - Justin Bieber",
        "description": "Baby (Feat. Ludacris) by Justin Bieber on Grooveshark",
        "link": "http://listen.grooveshark.com/s/Baby+Feat+Ludacris+/2Bqvdq",
        "pubDate": "Wed, 28 Apr 2010 02:37:53 -0400",
        "pubTime": 1272436673,
        "TinyLink": "http://tinysong.com/d3wI",
        "SongID": "24447862",
        "SongName": "Baby (Feat. Ludacris)",
        "ArtistID": "1118876",
        "ArtistName": "Justin Bieber",
        "AlbumID": "4104002",
        "AlbumName": "My World (Part II);\nhttp://tinysong.com/gQsw",
        "LongLink": "11578982",
        "GroovesharkLink": "11578982",
        "Link": "http://tinysong.com/d3wI"
    },
    {
        "title": "Feel Good Inc - Gorillaz",
        "description": "Feel Good Inc by Gorillaz on Grooveshark",
        "link": "http://listen.grooveshark.com/s/Feel+Good+Inc/1UksmI",
        "pubDate": "Wed, 28 Apr 2010 02:25:30 -0400",
        "pubTime": 1272435930
    }
]
```

I tried using a dictionary:

```
def getLastSong(user,limit):
    base_url = 'http://gsuser.com/lastSong/'
    user_url = base_url + str(user) + '/' + str(limit) + "/"
    raw = urllib.urlopen(user_url)
    json_raw= raw.readlines()
    json_object = json.loads(json_raw[0])

    #filtering and making it look good.
    gsongs = []
    print json_object
    for song in json_object[0]:   
        print song
```

This code only prints the information before `:`.
(*ignore the Justin Bieber track* :))

Answer (score 113, accepted):

Your loading of the JSON data is a little fragile. Instead of:

```
json_raw= raw.readlines()
json_object = json.loads(json_raw[0])
```

you should really just do:

```
json_object = json.load(raw)
```

You shouldn't think of what you get as a "JSON object". What you have is a list. The list contains two dicts. The dicts contain various key/value pairs, all strings. When you do `json_object[0]`, you're asking for the first dict in the list. When you iterate over that, with `for song in json_object[0]:`, you iterate over the keys of the dict. Because that's what you get when you iterate over the dict. If you want to access the value associated with the key in that dict, you would use, for example, `json_object[0][song]`.

None of this is specific to JSON. It's just basic Python types, with their basic operations as covered in any tutorial.

Comment: i don't get it. i tried to iterate through what your saying says out of bounds. i am pretty sure its a question about json

Comment: No. I'm telling you that iterating over the dict gives you the keys. If you want to iterate over something else, you'll have to iterate over something else. You didn't say what you wanted to iterate over. A Python tutorial would be a good place to find out what you can iterate over, and what it would do.

Comment: Unfortunately it's a little hard to explain all the ways you can extract data from lists and dictionaries and strings in the 600 characters you can put in a comment. I already said you should index the dict to get at the value associated with a key. I'm not sure what you want to iterate over. Learning about built-in Python types is the next step.

Comment: There's not much iteration involved when you want to get individual items. Perhaps what you want to iterate over is `json_object`, not `json_object[0]`, and then get individual items from each dict.

Answer (score 162):

I believe you probably meant:

```
from __future__ import print_function

for song in json_object:
    # now song is a dictionary
    for attribute, value in song.items():
        print(attribute, value) # example usage
```

NB: You could use `song.iteritems` instead of `song.items` if in Python 2.

Comment: for attribute, value in song.iteritems(): what does the comma in this line signify?

Comment: It's the same as `for (attribute, value) in song.iteritems():`, or `(var1, var2) = (1, 2)` or `var1, var2 = 1, 2`. `dict.iteritems()` produces `(key, value)` pairs (tuples). Search for “python tuple unpacking”.

Comment: For python 3, change `song.iteritems` to `song.items`.

Answer (score 62):

This question has been out here a long time, but I wanted to contribute how I usually iterate through a JSON object.  In the example below, I've shown a hard-coded string that contains the JSON, but the JSON string could just as easily have come from a web service or a file.

```
import json

def main():

    # create a simple JSON array
    jsonString = '{"key1":"value1","key2":"value2","key3":"value3"}'

    # change the JSON string into a JSON object
    jsonObject = json.loads(jsonString)

    # print the keys and values
    for key in jsonObject:
        value = jsonObject[key]
        print("The key and value are ({}) = ({})".format(key, value))

    pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: There is no string subscripting in the code above; `jsonObject` is a `dict`.
In the code above, I would prefer `for key, value in jsonObject.items():`.

Answer (score 30):

After deserializing the JSON, you have a python object. Use the regular object methods.

In this case you have a list made of dictionaries:

```
json_object[0].items()

json_object[0]["title"]
```

etc.

Answer (score 8):

I would solve this problem more like this

```
import json
import urllib2

def last_song(user, limit):
    # Assembling strings with "foo" + str(bar) + "baz" + ... generally isn't 
    # as nice as using real string formatting. It can seem simpler at first, 
    # but leaves you less happy in the long run.
    url = 'http://gsuser.com/lastSong/%s/%d/' % (user, limit)

    # urllib.urlopen is deprecated in favour of urllib2.urlopen
    site = urllib2.urlopen(url)

    # The json module has a function load for loading from file-like objects, 
    # like the one you get from `urllib2.urlopen`. You don't need to turn 
    # your data into a string and use loads and you definitely don't need to 
    # use readlines or readline (there is seldom if ever reason to use a 
    # file-like object's readline(s) methods.)
    songs = json.load(site)

    # I don't know why "lastSong" stuff returns something like this, but 
    # your json thing was a JSON array of two JSON objects. This will 
    # deserialise as a list of two dicts, with each item representing 
    # each of those two songs.
    #
    # Since each of the songs is represented by a dict, it will iterate 
    # over its keys (like any other Python dict). 
    baby, feel_good = songs

    # Rather than printing in a function, it's usually better to 
    # return the string then let the caller do whatever with it. 
    # You said you wanted to make the output pretty but you didn't 
    # mention *how*, so here's an example of a prettyish representation
    # from the song information given.
    return "%(SongName)s by %(ArtistName)s - listen at %(link)s" % baby
```

Answer (score 5):

For Python 3, you have to decode the data you get back from the web server. For instance I decode the data as utf8 then deal with it:

```python3
    # example of json data object group with two values of key id
    jsonstufftest = '{"group": {"id": "2", "id": "3"}}
    # always set your headers
    headers = {"User-Agent": "Moz & Woz"}
    # the url you are trying to load and get json from
    url = "http://www.cooljson.com/cooljson.json"
    # in python 3 you can build the request using request.Request 
    req = urllib.request.Request(url, None, headers)
    # try to connect or fail gracefully
    try:
        response = urllib.request.urlopen(req) # new python 3 code -jc
    except:
        exit('could not load page, check connection')
    # read the response and DECODE
    html=response.read().decode('utf8') # new python3 code
    # now convert the decoded string into real JSON
    loadedjson = json.loads(html)
    # print to make sure it worked
    print (loadedjson) # works like a charm
    # iterate through each key value
    for testdata in loadedjson['group']:
        print (accesscount['id']) # should print 2 then 3 if using test json
```

If you don't decode you will get bytes vs string errors in Python 3.

Comment: wondering if your accesscount will punch out a error? I think testdata['id'] might make things work a little better in your final loop.

Answer (score 4):

for iterating through JSON you can use this:

```
json_object = json.loads(json_file)
for element in json_object: 
    for value in json_object['Name_OF_YOUR_KEY/ELEMENT']:
        print(json_object['Name_OF_YOUR_KEY/ELEMENT']['INDEX_OF_VALUE']['VALUE'])
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding another solution (Python 3) - Iterating over json files in a directory and on each file iterating over all objects and printing relevant fields.

See comments in the code.

```
import os,json

data_path = '/path/to/your/json/files'  

# 1. Iterate over directory
directory = os.fsencode(data_path)
for file in os.listdir(directory):
    filename = os.fsdecode(file)
    # 2. Take only json files
    if filename.endswith(".json"):
        file_full_path=data_path+filename
        # 3. Open json file 
        with open(file_full_path, encoding='utf-8', errors='ignore') as json_data:
            data_in_file = json.load(json_data, strict=False)
            # 4. Iterate over objects and print relevant fields
            for json_object in data_in_file:
                print("ttl: %s, desc: %s" % (json_object['title'],json_object['description']) )
```

Comment: I would concatenate paths only by using 'os.path.join(data_path,filename)' to be compatible with different operating systems.

Answer (score 0):

If you can store the json string in a variable `jsn_string`

```
import json

jsn_list = json.loads(json.dumps(jsn_string)) 
   for lis in jsn_list:
       for key,val in lis.items():
           print(key, val)
```

Output :

```
title Baby (Feat. Ludacris) - Justin Bieber
description Baby (Feat. Ludacris) by Justin Bieber on Grooveshark
link http://listen.grooveshark.com/s/Baby+Feat+Ludacris+/2Bqvdq
pubDate Wed, 28 Apr 2010 02:37:53 -0400
pubTime 1272436673
TinyLink http://tinysong.com/d3wI
SongID 24447862
SongName Baby (Feat. Ludacris)
ArtistID 1118876
ArtistName Justin Bieber
AlbumID 4104002
AlbumName My World (Part II);
http://tinysong.com/gQsw
LongLink 11578982
GroovesharkLink 11578982
Link http://tinysong.com/d3wI
title Feel Good Inc - Gorillaz
description Feel Good Inc by Gorillaz on Grooveshark
link http://listen.grooveshark.com/s/Feel+Good+Inc/1UksmI
pubDate Wed, 28 Apr 2010 02:25:30 -0400
pubTime 1272435930
```