# batch upload json to dynamodb using boto3

Tags: python-3.x, boto3

I would like to batch upload a json file to dynamodb. At the moment I can successfully manually put items in a python file (as below) and upload to a table, however how can I amend the script to read an external json file (containing 200 items) and batch upload all 200 items to the table.

```
import boto3

dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb')
table = dynamodb.Table('exampletable')

with table.batch_writer() as batch:
    batch.put_item(
        Item={
            'ID': '2',
            'DateTime': '21/12/2017 13:16',
            'SourceDevice': '10',
            'DestinationDevice': '20',
            'DataType': 'full',
            'Activity': 'unusual'

    }
)
    batch.put_item(
        Item={
            'ID': '3',
            'DateTime': '21/12/2017 13:40',
            'SourceDevice': '10',
            'DestinationDevice': '20',
            'DataType': 'full',
            'Activity': 'unusual'

    }
)
```

json file contents as below

```
[{
"ID": "1",
"DateTime": "21/12/2017 13:16",
"SourceDevice": "10",
"DestinationDevice": "20",
"DataType": "part",
"Activity": "normal"
}, {
"ID": "1",
"DateTime": "21/12/2017 13:16",
"SourceDevice": "40",
"DestinationDevice": "25",
"DataType": "full",
"Activity": "unusual"
}]
```

Comment: Underrated question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You would simply break that down into two tasks:

1. Reading the JSON from a file
2. Looping through the JSON, calling `batch.put_item` each time.

There are [lots of results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20199126/reading-json-from-a-file) when you do a search for the first task. And the second task is literally [just writing a loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2733813/iterating-through-a-json-object).

A full solution would look something like this:

```
import json
import boto3

dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb')
table = dynamodb.Table('exampletable')

# Read the JSON file
with open('items.json') as json_data:
    items = json.load(json_data)

    with table.batch_writer() as batch:

        # Loop through the JSON objects
        for item in items:
            batch.put_item(Item=item)
```

Comment: thanks I was way overthinking this using boto3 and getting myself confused. Your answer worked perfectly