# How to loop through json data with multiple objects

Tags: python, json, dictionary

My json file `data.json` looks like this

```
[
{"host" : "192.168.0.25", "username":"server2", "path":"/home/server/.ssh/01_id"},
{"host" : "192.168.0.26", "username":"server3", "path":"/home/server/.ssh/01_id"}
]
```

I want the loop happen in this way only (lets ignore the remote variable)

```
for remotes,host,username in zip(remote , data["host"] ,data["username"]):
```

This is the error i am getting

```
    for remotes,host,username in list(zip(remote , data["host"] ,data["username"])):
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Iterating through a JSON object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2733813/iterating-through-a-json-object)

Comment: @HimanshuPoddar , No it doesnt

Comment: @HimanshuPoddar , i have a code which comes within `for remotes,host,username in zip(remote , data["host"] ,data["username"]):` and for loop i required for that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to iterate the data to extract the `host` and `username` values so that you can `zip` them to the `remote` list:

```py
data = [
 {"host" : "192.168.0.25", "username":"server2", "path":"/home/server/.ssh/01_id"},
 {"host" : "192.168.0.26", "username":"server3", "path":"/home/server/.ssh/01_id"}
]
hosts_users = [(d['host'], d['username']) for d in data]
remote = [1, 2]

for remote, (host, username) in zip(remote, hosts_users):
    print(remote, host, username)
```

Output:

```
1 192.168.0.25 server2
2 192.168.0.26 server3
```

Answer (score 0):

if you have `json` file first you need to read and after that, you can manipulate that data as a python object

```py
import json

with open("data.json") as json_file:
    data = json.load(json_file)

for d in data:
    host = d['host']
    username = d['username']
    path = d['path']
    print(host, username, path)
```

Comment: I have read the file and then manipulated the data as well as so i did this
`for remotes,host,username in zip(remote , data["host"] ,data["username"]):
`
The error is this ```TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str```

Comment: you don't need zip function you can reach host, and username directly check the code.

Answer (score 0):

You can do by using **map** with **zip** like

```
# uncomment following code if data reside in json
# import json
# file = open('path_of_your_json')
# data = json.load(file)
```

```
data = [
    {"host" : "192.168.0.25", "username":"server2", "path":"/home/server/.ssh/01_id"},
    {"host" : "192.168.0.26", "username":"server3", "path":"/home/server/.ssh/01_id"}
]

for (host, username, path) in zip(*zip(*map(lambda x: x.values(), data))): 
   print(host, username, path)   
   # whatever you want
```

**zip(*zip(*map(lambda x: x.values(), data)))** this line will provide the data in linear way

Answer (score -1):

Since you mentioned specifically that you would like to iterate through the data using zip column wise, here is how you can do that.

Say the json file name is SO.json

Load the json object in the variable data.

```
import json
f = open(r'C:\Users\YYName\Desktop\Temp\SO.json')
data = json.load(f)
```

Now you can iterate through the values using zip and through columns. Load the json data in a pandas dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
for host,username in zip(df["host"] ,df["username"]):
    print(host, username)
```

Assuming remote to be of same length as the number of rows in your json.  You can now do

```
for remotes,host,username in zip(remote , df["host"] ,df["username"]):
    print(remotes, host, username)
```