# how to access objects in python with for loop in different files

Tags: python

This is my `file1.json`:

```
{
    "count": 1,
    "next": null,
    "previous": null,
    "results": [
        {
            "id": 5883,
            "url": "https://some.api.com/api/ipam/ip-addresses/5883/",
            "display": "1.1.1.130/24",
            "family": {
                "value": 4,
                "label": "IPv4"
            },
            "address": "1.1.1.130/24",
            "vrf": null,
            "tenant": null,
            "status": {
                "value": "active",
                "label": "Active"
            },
            "role": null,
            "assigned_object_type": "dcim.interface",
            "assigned_object_id": 801,
            "assigned_object": {
                "id": 801,
                "url": "https://some.api.com/api/dcim/interfaces/801/",
                "display": "N2",
                "device": {
                    "id": 123,
                    "url": "https://some.api.com/api/dcim/devices/123/",
                    "display": "A-F3-G23-15-Saeed Unit15",
                    "name": "A-F3-G23-15-Saeed Unit15"
                },
                "name": "N2",
                "cable": null,
                "_occupied": false
            },
            "nat_inside": null,
            "nat_outside": null,
            "dns_name": "",
            "description": "",
            "tags": [],
            "custom_fields": {},
            "created": "2023-10-01",
            "last_updated": "2023-10-01T14:05:32.001606+03:30"
        }
    ]
}
```

This is my `file2.json`:

```
{
    "count": 1,
    "next": null,
    "previous": null,
    "results": [
        {
            "id": 6883,
            "url": "https://some.api.com/api/ipam/ip-addresses/6883/",
            "display": "2.2.2.130/24",
            "family": {
                "value": 4,
                "label": "IPv4"
            },
            "address": "2.2.2.130/24",
            "vrf": null,
            "tenant": null,
            "status": {
                "value": "active",
                "label": "Active"
            },
            "role": null,
            "assigned_object_type": "dcim.interface",
            "assigned_object_id": 901,
            "assigned_object": {
                "id": 901,
                "url": "https://some.api.com/api/dcim/interfaces/901/",
                "display": "N2",
                "device": {
                    "id": 123,
                    "url": "https://some.api.com/api/dcim/devices/223/",
                    "display": "A-F3-G23-16-Saeed Unit16",
                    "name": "A-F3-G23-16-Saeed Unit16"
                },
                "name": "N2",
                "cable": null,
                "_occupied": false
            },
            "nat_inside": null,
            "nat_outside": null,
            "dns_name": "",
            "description": "",
            "tags": [],
            "custom_fields": {},
            "created": "2023-10-01",
            "last_updated": "2023-10-01T14:05:32.001606+03:30"
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to use a `for` loop to iterate over both files (in real, there are more files with different names) and access `assigned_object['name']`.

Expected output is either of these (not sure which one is applicable):

1. "name": "A-F3-G23-15-Saeed Unit15"
2. "name": "A-F3-G23-16-Saeed Unit16"

OR

1. A-F3-G23-15-Saeed Unit15
2. A-F3-G23-16-Saeed Unit16

This is my attempt (not really sure the way to properly use `for` loop for files of the current path):

```
import json

file_name = 'file1.json'

with open(file_name) as file:
    data = json.load(file)

print(data['assigned_object["name"]'])
```

I get this error:

```
KeyError: 'assigned_object["name"]'
```

Comment: You meant something like `data['assigned_object']["name"]`

Comment: @ThierryLathuille thanks, but I still get `KeyError: 'assigned_object'`

Comment: Yes, because there are many levels above this one.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to loop through json data with multiple objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72612798/how-to-loop-through-json-data-with-multiple-objects)

Answer (score 2):

```
import json

file_name = 'file1.json'

with open(file_name) as file:
    data = json.load(file)

data["results"][0]["assigned_object"]["device"]["name"]

A-F3-G23-15-Saeed Unit15
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not accessing the attribute corectlly

```
import json

file_name = 'file1.json'

with open(file_name) as file:
   data = json.load(file)

print(data["results"][0]["assigned_object"])
```

and if you want to iterate on all the results you could use this code :

```
import json

file_name = 'file1.json'

with open(file_name) as file:
   data = json.load(file)

for element in data["results"]:
   print(element["assigned_object"])
```