# TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str over a big and merged json file

Tags: python

This is `combined.json`:

```
[
    {
        "count": 1,
        "next": null,
        "previous": null,
        "results": [
            {
                "id": 5883,
                "url": "https://some.api.com/api/ipam/ip-addresses/5883/",
                "display": "1.1.1.130/24",
                "family": {
                    "value": 4,
                    "label": "IPv4"
                },
                "address": "1.1.1.130/24",
                "vrf": null,
                "tenant": null,
                "status": {
                    "value": "active",
                    "label": "Active"
                },
                "role": null,
                "assigned_object_type": "dcim.interface",
                "assigned_object_id": 801,
                "assigned_object": {
                    "id": 801,
                    "url": "https://some.api.com/api/dcim/interfaces/801/",
                    "display": "N2",
                    "device": {
                        "id": 123,
                        "url": "https://some.api.com/api/dcim/devices/123/",
                        "display": "A-F3-G23-15-Saeed Unit15",
                        "name": "A-F3-G23-15-Saeed Unit15"
                    },
                    "name": "N2",
                    "cable": null,
                    "_occupied": false
                },
                "nat_inside": null,
                "nat_outside": null,
                "dns_name": "",
                "description": "",
                "tags": [],
                "custom_fields": {},
                "created": "2023-10-01",
                "last_updated": "2023-10-01T14:05:32.001606+03:30"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "count": 1,
        "next": null,
        "previous": null,
        "results": [
            {
                "id": 6883,
                "url": "https://some.api.com/api/ipam/ip-addresses/6883/",
                "display": "2.2.2.130/24",
                "family": {
                    "value": 4,
                    "label": "IPv4"
                },
                "address": "2.2.2.130/24",
                "vrf": null,
                "tenant": null,
                "status": {
                    "value": "active",
                    "label": "Active"
                },
                "role": null,
                "assigned_object_type": "dcim.interface",
                "assigned_object_id": 901,
                "assigned_object": {
                    "id": 901,
                    "url": "https://some.api.com/api/dcim/interfaces/901/",
                    "display": "N2",
                    "device": {
                        "id": 123,
                        "url": "https://some.api.com/api/dcim/devices/223/",
                        "display": "A-F3-G23-16-Saeed Unit16",
                        "name": "A-F3-G23-16-Saeed Unit16"
                    },
                    "name": "N2",
                    "cable": null,
                    "_occupied": false
                },
                "nat_inside": null,
                "nat_outside": null,
                "dns_name": "",
                "description": "",
                "tags": [],
                "custom_fields": {},
                "created": "2023-10-01",
                "last_updated": "2023-10-01T14:05:32.001606+03:30"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

I want to access all elements in `["results"][0]["assigned_object"]["device"]["name"]` with the following code (this code is given from my other question: [how to access objects in python with for loop in different files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77249378)):

```
import json

file_name = 'combined.json'

with open(file_name) as file:
    data = json.load(file)

data["results"][0]["assigned_object"]["device"]["name"]

### OR EVEN THIS ###
import json

file_name = 'combined.json'

with open(file_name) as file:
   data = json.load(file)

for element in data["results"]:
   print(element["assigned_object"]["device"]['name'])
```

But I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

I just can be sure the syntax of `combined.json` is correct, but I'm not sure why it doesn't print all of what I want.

This is the expected output:

```
A-F3-G23-15-Saeed Unit15
A-F3-G23-16-Saeed Unit16
```

I checked the syntax of my merged `json` file and that is correct.

Comment: @TomKarzes thanks my friend, but I think my steps before error are correct. I first print the object in small file and they're correct. Then I merge both files and check the syntax which is still correct. But the final step to iterate over doesn't work properly

Comment: @TomKarzes question updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code gives the required output.

```py
import json

file_name = 'combined.json'

with open(file_name) as file:
   data = json.load(file)

for element in data:
   print(element["results"][0]["assigned_object"]["device"]["name"])
```

The top-level data is a list of dictionaries, so trying to access the value of "results" directly will result in an error. The `element["results"]` object is a list (as per the JSON). It seems there is only one element in it, so it can be accessed using the 0 index.

Comment: Thanks, but with the real `json` file I get `TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable`. I have some `"results": []` which are empty. I first suspected they're raising issue. I removed them but I'm still getting this error. Is the error relating to one of the objects are empty? Or it's something else?

Comment: I don't know, if you removed the results which are empty, did you just remove the results field, or the entire item from the global list? Also, it is possible that any of the elements from your nested dictionaries may be empty as well (assigned_object, device). My code will only work assuming that the structure of the file remains the same as in the example file, it works on the example which you have given (I have tried to run it before giving the answer)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes, I checked every object and there were only two `"results": []` and I removed them but I still have this error. All other objects `assigned_object, device, name` have value and none of them are empty. Thanks. I ran your code with my sample and it worked but I didn't know my real json file has some empty values before.